# 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.' al insertar datos en SQL SERVER 2012, con Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Qué tal buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente problema con un STORE PROCEDURE. Al momento de insertar datos para una tabla, me marca el siguiente error 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'. Cabe resaltar que el proceso ya funcionaba, pero al agregar un campo que se llama Transferencia, me dejó de funcionar. El proceso lo adapté para que pudiera recibir el campo Transferencia y desde ahí ya no me deja insertar los datos en la tabla por el error mencionado anteriormente, el query que inserta en la tabla está emparejado al orden de las columnas en la definición de mi tabla ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué me arroja este error?

Este es el código de mi STORE PROCEDURE

````
```ALTER PROCEDURE GuardaHojaPaciente /*Proceso que almacena la hoja de control de
     * pacientes junto con sus detalles de servicios.
     Recibe una serialización en XML para su hoja y
     detalle.
     Creado el 11/03/2021*/
    @hojaControl XML,
    @detalleServicio XML,
    @Mensaje varchar(200) out AS BEGIN BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    
    DECLARE @handle INT;
    
    DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT;
    
    declare @IdConsulta INT;
    
    EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus = sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT,
    @hojaControl;
    
    INSERT
        INTO
        Hoja_Pacientes(Fecha, --26/03/2021
        Folio,
        Id_Paciente,
        Nombre_Paciente,
        Id_Tipo_Paciente,
        Tipo_Paciente,
        Es_Convenio,
        Cita,
        Monto,
        Efectivo,
        Tarjeta,
        AMEX,
        Monto_Cobrado,
        Id_Empleado,
        Empleado,
        Turno,
        Id_Medico,
        Medico,
        Fecha_Hora,
        Id_Sucursal,
        Sucursal,
        Primera_Vez,
        Adeudo,
        Edo_Cobro,
        Impuesto_IVA,
        Factura_Mensual,
        Transferencia )
    SELECT
        FechaHojaControl 'Fecha',
        NumFolio 'Folio',
        IdPaciente 'Id_Paciente',
        NombrePaciente 'Nombre_Paciente',
        IdTipoPaciente 'Id_Tipo_Paciente',
        TipoPaciente 'Tipo_Paciente',
        EsConvenio 'Es_Convenio',
        CitaPaciente 'Cita',
        Monto,
        Efectivo,
        TarjetaCredito 'Tarjeta',
        AExpress 'AMEX',
        MontoCobrado 'Monto_Cobrado',
        IdEmpleado 'Id_Empleado',
        Empleado 'Empleado',
        TurnoRecepcionista 'Turno',
        IdMedico 'Id_Medico',
        Medico,
        FechaAtencionPaciente 'Fecha_Hora',
        IdSucursal 'Id_Sucursal',
        Sucursal,
        PrimeraVez 'Primera_Vez',
        Adeudo,
        EdoCobro 'Edo_Cobro',
        ImpuestoIVA 'Impuesto_IVA',
        FacturaMensualTexto 'Factura_Mensual',
        Transferencia
    FROM
        OPENXML(@handle,
        '/clsOrdenCompra',
        2) WITH (
        --IdConsulta INT,
     FechaHojaControl date,
        NumFolio varchar(20),
        IdPaciente INT,
        NombrePaciente varchar(180),
        IdTipoPaciente INT,
        TipoPaciente varchar(20),
        EsConvenio varchar(1),
        CitaPaciente varchar(2),
        Monto real,
        Efectivo real,
        TarjetaCredito real,
        AExpress real,
        MontoCobrado real,
        IdEmpleado INT,
        Empleado varchar(50),
        TurnoRecepcionista varchar(1),
        IdMedico INT,
        Medico varchar(180),
        FechaAtencionPaciente datetime,
        IdSucursal INT,
        Sucursal varchar(50),
        PrimeraVez varchar(1),
        Adeudo real,
        EdoCobro varchar(1),
        ImpuestoIVA real,
        FacturaMensualTexto varchar(1),
        Transferencia real
        --26/03/2021
    ) ;
    
    SET
    @IdConsulta = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    --SCOPE_IDENTITY
     EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle;
    
    EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus = sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT,
    @detalleServicio;
    
    INSERT
        INTO
        Det_Servicio ( Id_Consulta,
        Id_Servicio,
        Nombre_Servicio,
        Clave_Servicio,
        Facturado_A,
        Numero_Factura,
        Precio_Servicio,
        Precio_Lista,
        Variacion,
        A_Cobrar_Servicio,
        Imp_A_Cobrar,
        IVA_Servicio,
        Ret_ISR_Servicio,
        Adeudo_Servicio,
        Efectivo_Servicio,
        AMEX_Servicio,
        Id_Medico,
        Medico_Ayudante,
        Cortesia,
        Tarjeta_Servicio,
        Transferencia_Servicio --26/03/2021
        )
    SELECT
        @IdConsulta as IdConsulta,
        detalleServXML.*
    FROM
        OPENXML(@handle,
        '/ArrayOfClsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra/clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra',
        2) WITH (
        --IdConsulta INT,
        IdServicio INT,
        NombreServicio varchar(50),
        ClaveServicio varchar(10),
        FacturadoServicio varchar(15),
        NumeroFacturadoRecibo varchar(20),
        PrecioServicio real,
        PrecioLista real,
        Variacion real,
        ACobrarServicio real,
        ImpACobrar real,
        IVAServicio real,
        RetISRServicio real,
        AdeudoServicio real,
        EfectivoServicio real,
        AMEXServicio real,
        IdMedico real,
        MedicoAyudante varchar(180),
        Cortesia varchar(2),
        TDCServicio real, 
        TransferenciaServicio real --26/03/2021
        ) As detalleServXML ;
    
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle;
    
    SET
    @Mensaje = 'Hoja registrada correctamente.' COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT 'Error Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS varchar(10));
    
    PRINT 'Error Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    
    PRINT 'Error Severity: ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS varchar(10));
    
    PRINT 'Error State: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS varchar(10));
    
    PRINT 'Error Line: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS varchar(10));
    
    PRINT 'Error Proc: ' + COALESCE(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
    'Not within procedure');
    --Set @Mensaje= ERROR_MESSAGE();
     /*IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 512
                Begin
                    Set @CuantosIdProd = (Select Count(Clave) From Catalogo Where Clave = @NumPart);
                    Set @Mensaje= 'Hay '+ STR(@CuantosIdProd,4) +' registros con ' + @NumPartAnt 
                                    + char(10)  + 'en el catálogo de refaciones.';
                End
                Else*/
    Set
    @Mensaje = CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS varchar(10)) + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
    END```
````

La definición de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Hoja_Pacientes (
    Id_Consulta int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Fecha date NULL,
    Folio varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Id_Paciente int NOT NULL,
    Nombre_Paciente varchar(180) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Id_Tipo_Paciente int NOT NULL,
    Tipo_Paciente varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Es_Convenio varchar(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Cita varchar(2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Monto real NULL,
    Efectivo real NULL,
    Tarjeta real NULL,
    AMEX real NULL,
    Monto_Cobrado real NULL,
    Id_Empleado int NOT NULL,
    Empleado varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Turno varchar(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Id_Medico int NOT NULL,
    Medico varchar(180) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Fecha_Hora datetime NULL,
    Id_Sucursal int NOT NULL,
    Sucursal varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Primera_Vez varchar(1) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    Adeudo real NULL,
    Edo_Cobro varchar(1) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    Impuesto_IVA real NULL,
    Factura_Mensual varchar(1) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    Transferencia real NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__Hoja_Pac__C658258896921716 PRIMARY KEY (Id_Consulta),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Hoja_Paci__Id_Em__05D8E0BE FOREIGN KEY (Id_Empleado) REFERENCES gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Empleados(Id_Empleado),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Hoja_Paci__Id_Me__06CD04F7 FOREIGN KEY (Id_Medico) REFERENCES gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Medicos(Id_Medico),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Hoja_Paci__Id_Pa__03F0984C FOREIGN KEY (Id_Paciente) REFERENCES gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Pacientes(Id_Paciente),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Hoja_Paci__Id_Su__07C12930 FOREIGN KEY (Id_Sucursal) REFERENCES gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Sucursal(Id_Sucursal),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Hoja_Paci__Id_Ti__04E4BC85 FOREIGN KEY (Id_Tipo_Paciente) REFERENCES gesfemco_DB_Pacientes_D.gesfemco_Admin_DV.Tipo_Paciente(Id_Tipo_Paciente)
) GO
```

También dejo un ejemplo de los objetos serializados en XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clsOrdenCompra>
  <IdConsulta>0</IdConsulta>
  <FechaHojaControl>2021-03-26T13:23:41</FechaHojaControl>
  <NumFolio>26/03/2021-1</NumFolio>
  <IdPaciente>3</IdPaciente>
  <NombrePaciente>PRUEBA PRUEBAAAAAAA PRUEBA</NombrePaciente>
  <IdTipoPaciente>64</IdTipoPaciente>
  <TipoPaciente>PARTICULAR</TipoPaciente>
  <EsConvenio>V</EsConvenio>
  <CitaPaciente>NO</CitaPaciente>
  <Monto>2950</Monto>
  <Efectivo>2000</Efectivo>
  <TarjetaCredito>500</TarjetaCredito>
  <AExpress>0</AExpress>
  <Transferencia>200</Transferencia>
  <MontoCobrado>2700</MontoCobrado>
  <IdEmpleado>2</IdEmpleado>
  <Empleado>Administrador</Empleado>
  <TurnoRecepcionista>M</TurnoRecepcionista>
  <IdMedico>17</IdMedico>
  <Medico>JORGE ORTEGA VEGA</Medico>
  <FechaAtencionPaciente>2021-03-26T13:23:41</FechaAtencionPaciente>
  <IdSucursal>1</IdSucursal>
  <Sucursal>MOCEL</Sucursal>
  <PrimeraVez>F</PrimeraVez>
  <Adeudo>250</Adeudo>
  <EdoCobro>P</EdoCobro>
  <FacturaMensual>false</FacturaMensual>
  <FacturaMensualTexto>F</FacturaMensualTexto>
  <ImpuestoIVA>406.896484</ImpuestoIVA>
  <PersonaMoral>false</PersonaMoral>
  <CancelarCargaServicios>false</CancelarCargaServicios>
  <Resultado />
</clsOrdenCompra>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfClsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
  <clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
    <IdDetServicio>0</IdDetServicio>
    <IdConsulta>0</IdConsulta>
    <IdServicio>3</IdServicio>
    <NombreServicio>ASPIRACIÓN /PUNSION MAMARIA </NombreServicio>
    <ClaveServicio>APS</ClaveServicio>
    <FacturadoServicio>GESFEM S.C.</FacturadoServicio>
    <NumeroFacturadoRecibo />
    <PrecioServicio>1200</PrecioServicio>
    <PrecioLista>1200</PrecioLista>
    <Variacion>0</Variacion>
    <ACobrarServicio>1200</ACobrarServicio>
    <ImpACobrar>1200</ImpACobrar>
    <IVAServicio>165.517212</IVAServicio>
    <RetISRServicio>0</RetISRServicio>
    <AdeudoServicio>101.694916</AdeudoServicio>
    <EfectivoServicio>813.5593</EfectivoServicio>
    <TDCServicio>203.389832</TDCServicio>
    <AMEXServicio>0</AMEXServicio>
    <TransferenciaServicio>81.3559341</TransferenciaServicio>
    <IdMedico>-1</IdMedico>
    <MedicoAyudante>NO APLICA</MedicoAyudante>
    <Cortesia>NO</Cortesia>
    <Resultado />
  </clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
  <clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
    <IdDetServicio>0</IdDetServicio>
    <IdConsulta>0</IdConsulta>
    <IdServicio>9</IdServicio>
    <NombreServicio>BIOPSIA MAMARIA</NombreServicio>
    <ClaveServicio>BOIMA</ClaveServicio>
    <FacturadoServicio>GESFEM S.C.</FacturadoServicio>
    <NumeroFacturadoRecibo />
    <PrecioServicio>1000</PrecioServicio>
    <PrecioLista>1000</PrecioLista>
    <Variacion>0</Variacion>
    <ACobrarServicio>1000</ACobrarServicio>
    <ImpACobrar>1000</ImpACobrar>
    <IVAServicio>137.931015</IVAServicio>
    <RetISRServicio>0</RetISRServicio>
    <AdeudoServicio>84.7457657</AdeudoServicio>
    <EfectivoServicio>677.9661</EfectivoServicio>
    <TDCServicio>169.491531</TDCServicio>
    <AMEXServicio>0</AMEXServicio>
    <TransferenciaServicio>67.79661</TransferenciaServicio>
    <IdMedico>-1</IdMedico>
    <MedicoAyudante>NO APLICA</MedicoAyudante>
    <Cortesia>NO</Cortesia>
    <Resultado />
  </clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
  <clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
    <IdDetServicio>0</IdDetServicio>
    <IdConsulta>0</IdConsulta>
    <IdServicio>19</IdServicio>
    <NombreServicio>CITOLOGIA BASE LIQUIDA </NombreServicio>
    <ClaveServicio>CITBL</ClaveServicio>
    <FacturadoServicio>GESFEM S.C.</FacturadoServicio>
    <NumeroFacturadoRecibo />
    <PrecioServicio>750</PrecioServicio>
    <PrecioLista>750</PrecioLista>
    <Variacion>0</Variacion>
    <ACobrarServicio>750</ACobrarServicio>
    <ImpACobrar>750</ImpACobrar>
    <IVAServicio>103.448257</IVAServicio>
    <RetISRServicio>0</RetISRServicio>
    <AdeudoServicio>63.5593224</AdeudoServicio>
    <EfectivoServicio>508.474579</EfectivoServicio>
    <TDCServicio>127.118645</TDCServicio>
    <AMEXServicio>0</AMEXServicio>
    <TransferenciaServicio>50.8474579</TransferenciaServicio>
    <IdMedico>-1</IdMedico>
    <MedicoAyudante>NO APLICA</MedicoAyudante>
    <Cortesia>NO</Cortesia>
    <Resultado />
  </clsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
</ArrayOfClsDetalleServicioOrdenCompra>
```

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo Barrera, creo que la sentencia del SP es alter puesto agregaste una columna como lo comentas, create es cuando creas un SP nuevo alter para modificar el SP.

Comment: esa consulta con la que haces la inserción, te devuelve el dato nuevo?

Comment: @JDanielSolisV Sí, de hecho es un alter y no tiene problema al modificar el proceso. El problema viene cuando se llama al proceso, que es cuando me manda el error. Los objetos que recibe como parámetro se mandan serializados en XML desde una aplicación en .NET

Comment: @L.Ronquillo, lo que hace es insertar los datos en ambas tablas, la primera es de datos principales y la segunda es de detalles de la primera. El resultado se refleja en ambas tablas.

Comment: sí, entiendo esa parte, pero en tu insert es a base de un select, ese select, te devuelve **todos** los datos que necesitas? porque si no, por ahí puede ir el error

Comment: @L.Ronquillo ya encontré el origen del error. Resulta que la table Hoja_Pacientes, al insertar una fila tiene un trigger que actualiza otra tabla donde también se tiene que insertar el campo Trasferencia que también se tiene que agregar. De todos modos muchas gracias por las respuestas.